# Google Docs for iOS

Tags: ios5, ios4, google-drive-api, google-docs-api

Is there any Google Docs SDK or wrapper for iOS ? OR we need to do it from scratch via Google APIs ?

Thanks.

Best regards,
Henry Fok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a GData library in Objective-C http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/ with Documents List API component http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FSource%2FClients%2FDocs

Answer (score 0):

Just to note, many of the most prominent Google APIs have been replaced by their JSON API which has a separate Obj-C client available here:

http://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/